# From where to use TokenHelper class for client context in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, oauth

I have been reading several articles to get SharePoint Online client context with the generated access token. All of them use `TokenHelper` class to get the client context as shown below:

```
ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(targetWeb, AccessToken);
```

My question is how do we access `TokenHelper` class? I could not find it in the reference Microsoft.SharePoint.Client version 16.1.0.0. What reference do we need to add to access this class?

Comment: I am not able to add AppForSharePointOnlineWebToolkit 3 in my visual studio 2013

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add the NuGet package [AppForSharePointOnlineWebToolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AppForSharePointOnlineWebToolkit). It will add the TokenHelper.cs and SharePointContext.cs files to your project.

Answer (score 4):

Make Sure that you   installed  [Office  developer Tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/04/26/the-latest-of-microsoft-office-developer-tools-office-add-in-commands-and-sharepoint-2016-support/) and [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35585)

We  don't need any external Reference for the  SharePointContext.cs and TokenHelper.cs files.  Once we create the  provider hosted app, they will come in the VS   Web Project automatically.

If they are not  present in the Provider hosted app  Web project, please re  [install the Office  developer Tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/11/23/latest-microsoft-office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2015/)